# Solving the problem of installing the balebot module

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I get this error when I try to install the balebot module

```
  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z_y3nkeg\pillow_7e69988e761f4b73a94eb117fcfefbf8\setup.py", line 760, in <module>
      setup(name=NAME,
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 346, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z_y3nkeg\pillow_7e69988e761f4b73a94eb117fcfefbf8\setup.py", line 582, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z_y3nkeg\pillow_7e69988e761f4b73a94eb117fcfefbf8\setup.py", line 807, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

```
**balebot is a module to create a bot for a messenger**
```

I first tried to install the balebot module and it was completely installed until I got to the pillow module and this error occurred during the installation.

The commands I typed :

```
pip install balebot
pip install pillow
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show the full text of the error. "*Could not build wheels for pillow*" is not an error, it's just a resolution after the error. We cannot guess what have gone wrong.

Comment: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` — verify that you use 64-bit Python, not 32. This is important because Pillow [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files) for 64-bit Pythons for all OSes. If it's 32-bit uninstall it and install 64-bit Python 3.11.

Comment: If your Python is already 64-bit try `pip install --only-binary=pillow pillow` (Yes, `pillow` 2 times, one for `--only-binary` and the other for `pip`.)

Answer (score -1):

Not certain solution, i want to just share my idea ;

It seems to me Package installation error. I think it can be solved other pillow versions like upper or down. Also error explanation is give us a idea, your zlib packages can not be found by pillow compiling.

`The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.` I am not sure but you can check your pillow and python version according to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html.

After that you can install suitable pillow package. Lastly, you can pip install  pillow first, then balebot.

Answer (score -2):

This is a common error. You should try installing zlib first and then installing Pillow again.

`pip install zlib`

`pip install pillow`

Comment: `zlib` is a module from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html). One [cannot](https://pypi.org/project/zlib/) install it with `pip`.